# Nested flex boxes enclosing a SVG element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling flex `#main-container` below a `#header` div. Child elements of `#main-container` are `.box` elements which should vertically fill the space remaining in the container. Each of these elements has more nested elements of a UI which eventually contain a customs `svg` element.

I managed to do what I need with the code below, with the exception of horizontally sizing the `.box` element to fit the nested `svg` element, which is essentially a perfect circle. Right now, as the browser viewport grows in size, the `svg` element grows, and overflows (hidden) to the right. I would like the `svg` element to increase the width of either `.box` or `.box-container` *until the svg element vertically fills* the available vertical space inside `.svg-container`, and then stop increasing the `.box` width. I don't know what I'm missing in order to achieve this.

Also, is nesting flex boxes like this considered good practice? It seems overly complex for what is essentially a simple layout. Apart from the problem described above, it looks exactly as I need it to look (I've tested three modern browsers) but I don't know if it's a very convoluted approach or not.

```css
#app {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

/* Container horizontal flex box:
renders .box elements horizontally with scroll on overflow */
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    /* Vertically fill remaining space in #app */
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Vertical flex box:
fill available vertical space in #container */
.box {
    max-height: 50em;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* Extra wrapper allows round borders for boxes with "overflow: hidden"
while still allowing "overflow-x: scroll" in #container */
.box-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: var(--color-04);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-00);
    border-radius: 3em;
    /* Vertical flex container 
    allows pushing ".bottom-ui" to the bottom */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /* Needed for absolute positioning of close button inside .box */
    position: relative;
}

.top-ui {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    /* Push .bottom-ui down, flush with .box-container bottom */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.svg-container {
    /* Push rest of UI to the bottom */
    flex-grow: 1;
    /*
    adding this scales down the svg element to fit the main .box width
    instead of enlarging the box:

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    */
}

svg {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='app'>
    <div id='header'>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='box'>
            <div class='box-container'>
                <div class='top-ui'>
                    <div class='svg-container'>
                        <svg>
                    </div>
                    <!--- more stuff here --->
                </div>
                <div class='bottom-ui'>
                    <!--- more stuff here --->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```